# How to perform a statistical comparison between these two groups?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, variance, confounding

How would I compare these two groups?

[image]

In this case, this would be a comparison between group A and B, where the first group would contain the first two violin plots, and the second group would be contain two violin plots, where each violin plot is a different patient.

To summarize this comparison, I would be comparing group A to group B, each of which contains unique patients, and each patient has a distribution of values for what I want to compare. How would I be able to get a p value from this?